# Applying SVD throws a Memory Error instantaneously?

Tags: python, memory, numpy, nlp, scipy

I am trying to apply SVD on my matrix (3241 x 12596) that was obtained after some text processing (with the ultimate goal of performing Latent Semantic Analysis) and I am unable to understand why this is happening as my 64-bit machine has 16GB RAM. The moment `svd(self.A)` is called, it throws an error. The precise error is given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\SVD.py", line 985, in <module>
    _svd.calc()
  File ".\SVD.py", line 534, in calc
    self.U, self.S, self.Vt = svd(self.A)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_svd.py", line 81, in svd
    overwrite_a = overwrite_a)
MemoryError
```

So I tried using

```
self.U, self.S, self.Vt = svd(self.A, full_matrices= False)
```

and this time, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\SVD.py", line 985, in <module>
    _svd.calc()
  File ".\SVD.py", line 534, in calc
    self.U, self.S, self.Vt = svd(self.A, full_matrices= False)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\decomp_svd.py", line 71, in svd
    return numpy.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=0, compute_uv=compute_uv)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1317, in svd
    work = zeros((lwork,), t)
MemoryError
```

Is this supposed to be such a large matrix that Numpy cannot handle and is there something that I can do at this stage without changing the methodology itself?

Comment: How much memory is Python using at the point it tries to compute the SVD? Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: It is using 380 MB when it crashes. Ah! :( I am using a 32-bit Python. I will go ahead and install the 64-bit version.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: You are a real savior! Somehow that point skipped my mind. It works perfectly fine now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, as it turns out, thanks to @Ferdinand Beyer, I did not notice that I was using a 32-bit version of Python on my 64-bit machine.

Using a 64-bit version of Python and reinstalling all the libraries solved the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the `full_matrices` parameter to `scipy.linalg.svd` is important: your input is highly rank-deficient (rank max 3,241), so you don't want to allocate the entire 12,596 x 12,596 matrix for `V`!

More importantly, matrices coming from text processing are likely **very sparse**. The `scipy.linalg.svd` is dense and doesn't offer truncated SVD, which results in a) tragic performance and b) lots of wasted memory.

Have a look at the [sparseSVD](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sparsesvd) package from PyPI, which works over sparse input and you can ask for top `K` factors only. Or try `scipy.sparse.linalg.svd`, though that's not as efficient and only available in newer versions of scipy.

Or, to avoid the gritty details completely, use a package that does efficient LSA for you transparently, such as [gensim](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim).