# Using Global Contrast Normalization - Python pylearn2

Tags: python, global, contrast, pylearn

Im attempting to input my image to this method, but when i try to draw the image, it comes totally black.

I tried inputing just one image and inputing the whole MNIST dataset.
Same result.

https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/expr/preprocessing.py

```
if GCN is True:
    trainingFolder = "../inputData/converted_training/GCN/"
    testingFolder = "../inputData/converted_testing/GCN/"

    img0 = (data[1,1:]).reshape((28,28)).astype('uint8')*255
    im = Image.fromarray(img0)
    im.show()

    #GCN#
    img_gcn = global_contrast_normalize(data)
    img_gcn_1 = Image.fromarray(img_gcn[1,1:].reshape((28,28)).astype('uint8')*255)
    img_gcn_1.show()
```

The second image, which is img_gcn_1 comes blacked.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to visualize the image without multiplying by 255? *i.e.,*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = img_gcn[:, 0]
img = img.reshape(28, 28, order='F')    
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

I think that procedure should work.

Comment: img_gcn = global_contrast_normalize(data)
    #img_gcn = global_contrast_normalize(img0)

    ##img_gcn_1 = Image.fromarray(img_gcn[1,1:].reshape((28,28)).astype('uint8')*255)
    ##img_gcn_1.show()

    iimg = img_gcn[:, 0]
    img = img.reshape(28, 28, order='F')
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))                                                       img = img.reshape(28, 28, order='F')
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: What are the dimensions of img after trying to resize?

Comment: img.shape=  (42000L,)   .......................................printed from this :                                     img = img_gcn[:, 0]
    print "img.shape= ",img.shape
    img = img.reshape(28, 28, order='F')
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))

Comment: This works fine :     #GCN#
    data_to_gcn = data[:,1:]
    img_gcn = global_contrast_normalize(data_to_gcn)
    img = img_gcn[0,:]
    img = img.reshape(28, 28, order='F')
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
    plt.show()                                                                                                              but when i try to do it with imageFromArray, it comes blacked out

Comment: #GCN#
    data_to_gcn = data[:,1:]
    img_gcn = global_contrast_normalize(data_to_gcn)
    img = img_gcn[0,:]
    img = img.reshape(28, 28, order='F')
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
    #Works
    plt.show()


    #Fails
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    im.show()

Comment: What are the dimensions of data?

Comment: data.shape =  (42000L, 785L)
data_to_gcn.shape =  (42000L, 784L)

Comment: data has the first column to define label of the classifier. So i just jumped it.

Comment: Try extracting the image as img_gcn[0, ;] and the print it to console, if there are too many values near 0, then something is going wrong

Comment: #Fails
    #size = shape[1], shape[0]
    #IndexError: tuple index out of range
    im = Image.fromarray(img_gcn[0,:])
    im.show()

Comment: #Fails
    #size = shape[1], shape[0]
    #IndexError: tuple index out of range
    im = Image.fromarray(img_gcn[0,:].reshape(28, 28, order='F'))
    im.show()

Comment: Why do you want to use Image.fromarray?

Comment: Because i need to save the images into a folder.

Comment: Well you can do this! import matplotlib.image as mpimg mpimg.imsave('filename.png', img)

Comment: def rgb2gray(rgb):
    r, g, b = np.rollaxis(rgb[...,:3], axis = -1)
    return 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b   

This may help you to convert the RGB image into an B/W Image