# ZCA Whitening with opencv and java

Tags: java, scala, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement ZCA Whitening algorithm like shown here: [How to implement ZCA Whitening? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528800/how-to-implement-zca-whitening-python/38590790#38590790) with opencv in Scala (using Java api) but I cannot find the most of the functions used there (python with numpy).

So far I tried with this:

Loading image as Mat:

```
val input = Imgcodecs.imread(img)
Imgproc.cvtColor(input, input, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
input.convertTo(input, CvType.CV_64FC1)
```

Then apply the algorithm:

```
//Covariance matrix
val covar, mean = new Mat()
Core.calcCovarMatrix(input, covar, mean, Core.COVAR_NORMAL | Core.COVAR_ROWS) 
Core.divide(covar, new Scalar(input.rows - 1), covar)

//Singular Value Decomposition
val w, u, vt = new Mat()
Core.SVDecomp(covar, w, u, vt, Core.SVD_FULL_UV)

//#Whitening constant, it prevents division by zero
val  epsilon = 1e-5
```

To implement the last trasformation

```
ZCAMatrix = np.dot(U, np.dot(np.diag(1.0/np.sqrt(S + epsilon)), U.T))
```

I tried with:

```
var ZCAMatrix = new Mat
Core.add(w, new Scalar(epsilon), ZCAMatrix)
Core.sqrt(ZCAMatrix, ZCAMatrix)
Core.divide(1.0, ZCAMatrix, ZCAMatrix)
Core.gemm(Mat.diag(ZCAMatrix), u.t, 1, new Mat, 0, ZCAMatrix)
Core.gemm(u, ZCAMatrix, 1, new Mat, 0, ZCAMatrix)
```

Then apply the trasformation to the original image:

```
val output = new Mat
Core.gemm(ZCAMatrix, input, 1, new Mat, 0, output)
```

The result of thei transformation is: [image: this]

which is not exactly what it's supposed to be.
Can someone help?

Comment: In matrix multiplication there is importance in the order you multiply so i think you should use Core.gemm(u, ZCAMatrix, 1, new Mat, 0, ZCAMatrix)

Comment: you're right! tried with that, the result changes but it's still wrong.

Comment: @drstein it could be due to SVDecomp not returning non-square u (need to pass FULL_UV), while numpy by default return the full matrix. this is just a guess, I haven't tried to compile this. an easier way, perhaps, is to compute pca using opencv first then convert to zca.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with both suggestions, with the way I load the picture and with the new result.

Comment: @drstein, maybe it'll be easier to translate a C++ code into Java? You can look on the first section of the code here: http://www.compvision.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/991-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/

Comment: Does `val covar, mean = new Mat()` mean that you get two distinct new `Mat`s or that you get two references **to the same** `Mat` ?