# Decorrelating a large number of data using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, correlated

I'm trying to decorrelate a large number of correlated random variables. Specifically, I perform the following to generate a 1200 x 1000 set data, where 1200 is number of variables and 1000 is number of data points.

```
seed = 0
sample_size = 1000
n_var = 1200
total_rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=seed).randn(sample_size*n_var).reshape((n_var, sample_size))
```

The correlation for the generated numbers can be surprisingly large depending on the seed used (I've seen close to 0.1~0.2 time to time), and I need the variables to have close to 0 correlation (preferably within 1e-4, but anything less than 1e-2 could work as well).

I tried a lot of different methods such as Cholesky and ZCA ([How to implement ZCA Whitening? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528800/how-to-implement-zca-whitening-python)), but the former failed from positive definite condition while the latter simply could not bring the correlation close to 0 based on the criteria above.

Is there any way to reduce the correlation significantly? Or would this be the best I could do for such a large number of variables?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don’t need to keep the dimensionality, why don’t you do a PCA?

Comment: Actually, that's the thing - I need to keep the number of variables equal.