# SVD MemoryError in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, svd, arpack

I want to perform an SVD on a big array `M[159459,159459]`.

Since SVD computation depends on the input matrix of shape `(159459,159459)`, this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143723/applying-svd-throws-a-memory-error-instantaneously) does not address my goal.

I have tried to use:

- `scipy.linalg.svd`
- `scipy.linalg.svd(check_finite=False)`
- change the driver to `lapack_driver='gesvd`
- `numpy.linalg.svd`

However, I always get a MemoryError. Finally, I want to compute the full SVD, because I want to perform a [Procrustes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) analysis, i.e. if **M** is the matrix that I have now, I need **`M = USV'`**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

#M = np.load("M.npy")
M = np.random.rand(159459,159459)
U, s, Vh = linalg.svd(M, check_finite=False, lapack_driver='gesvd)
```

Everything fails.

My system details:

> `$ cat /proc/meminfo`
>   `MemTotal:     527842404 kB`
>   `MemFree:      523406068 kB`
>   `MemAvailable: 521659112 kB`

Comment: Does it help to use NumPy's [mmaps](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) instead of loading the input into memory? (If you are not already doing so, but I am not sure how much non in-place computation happen in SVD). Of course, when using *mmap*s expect substantially longer computation times.

Comment: I have not tried this. I will check it out

Comment: For a small approximate Procrustes matrix, take a look at [TruncatedSVD](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) in scikit-learn; start with `n_components=1000` or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Memory size matters, latency costs will hurt you next:

Given **`mM.shape == [159459, 159459]`**,
given `mM.dtype` is by default `float(64)`
there will be a need to have about:
**`203.42 [GB]`** for the ori ginal of **`mM[159459, 159459]`**, plus
**`203.42 [GB]`** for the computed **`mU[159459, 159459]`**, plus
**`203.42 [GB]`** for the computed **`Vh[159459, 159459]`**
**`0.0013 [GB]`** for the computed **`vS[159459]`**

A cheapest ever step, by trying a linear-only downscaling by a factor of 2 ( and not more than 4 ) from `float64` to `float32` or even `float16` is not the game changer and is even heavily penalised by `numpy` inefficiencies ( if not internally performed back-conversions up to `float64` again - my own attempts were so bleeding on this, that I share the resulting dissatisfaction here, so as to avoid repeating my own errors on trying to start with the lowest hanging fruit first ... )

In case your analysis may work just with the vector **`vS`**, only the `.svd( ..., compute_uv = False, ... )` flag will avoid making a space for about **`~ 1/2 [TB]` RAM-allocations** by not returning ( and thus not reserving space for them ) instances of **`mU`** and **`Vh`**.

Even such a case does not mean your SLOC will survive as is in the just about the reported `0.5 TB` RAM-system. The `scipy.linalg.svd()` processing will allocated internally working resources, that are outside of your scope of coding ( sure, unless you re-factor and re-design the `scipy.linalg` module on your own, which is fair to consider very probable if not sure ) and configuration control. So, be warned that even when you test the `compute_uv = False`-mode of processing, the `.svd()` may still throw an error, if it fails to internally allocate required internally used data-structures, that do not fit the current RAM.

This also means that even using the **`numpy.memmap()`**, which may be a successful trick to off-load the in-RAM representation of the original **`mM`** ( avoiding some remarkable part of the first needed **`203.4 [GB]`** from sitting and blocking the usage of the hosts RAM ), yet there are costs you will have to pay for using this trick.

My experiments, at smaller scales of the `.memmap`-s, used for matrix processing and in ML-optimisations, **yield about `1E4 ~ 1E6` slower processing** because, in spite of the smart caching, the `numpy.memmap()`-instances are dependent on the disk-I/O.

Best result will come from using advanced, `TB`-sized, SSD-only-storage devices, hosted right on the computing device on some fast and low-latency access-bus M.2 or PCIx16.

### The last piece of experience, one might not yet want to hear here:

Using larger host-based RAM, which means using a multi-TB computing device, is the safest way to go further. Testing the above proposed steps will help, if reduced performance and additional expenses are within your Project's budget. If not, go for the use of an HPC centre at your Alma Mater or at your Project's closest research centre, where such multi-TB computing devices are being used in common.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no easy and direct way for now. I need to compute U and V and not only S so `.svd( ..., compute_uv = False)` does not apply to my case.

Comment: **Always welcome** @serafeim There are multi-TB devices for doing this, check your Project's colleagues for the proper HPC resources.